# Compile applications using different toolchain than Linux system in embedded applications

Tags: c++, embedded, embedded-linux, glibc

I wonder if it is good idea to compile the applications for embedded system using different toolchain than is used to compile embedded Linux on which the applications will be run.

My problem here is that from vendor I get source of Linux system and all the drivers which I need in project. On the other side I have to write more complex software to manage this device in interaction with external user. I want to code using the C++ standard 11 however the toolchain which I obtain from vendor is from 2007 so it definitely not supports this standard.

My first thought is to use [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) to build my own cross compile toolchain with newer compiler and glibc/glibc++ to support the new standard. I assume that I've to use the headers from the old Linux which is delivered by vendor of my device. The Linux kernel is in 2.6.30.10 version. Can I in this way obtain a cross compilation toolchain which will be work or I should suspend this? What kind of problems can I obtain in that way.

Below I present output from `file` command on binaries from the code compiled using vendor toolchain

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.14, not stripped
```

Comment: I'm certainly no expert - but the biggest problem I've run into with such tool-chains is library compatibility.

Your newly-compiled software may run under the kernel, but can it use the vendor provided static libraries, will it correctly link to shared-libraries, etc?

Comment: Yes I think so. I discuss this also in our company and we decided to stay with old toolchain and probably C.  Anyway thanks for reply.

Comment: No problem, it's a sad state of affairs with modern hardware vendors.
Don't forget you can answer your own question ^_^

Comment: Kick that vendor in the buXX! Depending on your hardware, you can set up a complete system from source code. There are various well-managed embedded distributions available. Maybe you have to recompile or adopt the specific drivers for your hardware. It is possibly not a good idea just to use a new toolchain. But still no reason to stick with the old stuff.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: which platform are you talking about?

Comment: maybe port this device to openwrt sdk? i spent a week to this, but it save me a month of work